# Create UICollectionViewCell programmatically without nib or storyboard

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Is there a way to create `UICollectionViewCell` without using existing cell identifier and existing nib file in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: what about [UICollectionViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: When I do alloc and init only it requires to use `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`. When I do that, than program breaks and error is could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier accountCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: Search google for that error. You will find a question I wrote and answered from about 18 months ago.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its not necessary to use Storyboard/Xib for the CollectionViewCell. You can even create it programmatically. Subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and write up the code for the cell. Then in CollectionView controller class you have to register you custom cell class with the collectionView

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[CustomCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID];
```

You can have different cell class if you are using different type cells. Reuse identifier should be unique.

In ***cellForItemAtIndexPath*** use the proper identifier to dequeue

```
[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: in swift: ex: `self.myCollectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "identifier")`